# Using class name as method parameter and return type

Tags: c#

I have an extension method for deserialization of an `XDocument`.

I use `CarConfiguration` as variable in this method, but I have another class configurations:

```
public static CarConfiguration Deserialize(this XDocument xdoc)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CarConfiguration));

    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xdoc.ToString()))
    {
        CarConfiguration cfg = (CarConfiguration) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        return cfg;
    }
}

class CarConfiguration 
{
    //car 
}

class BikeConfiguration 
{
    //bike 
}
```

So, there are 2 questions here:

1. Can I use class name as parameter for this method? Something like this:

   ```
   static CarConfiguration Deserialize(this XDocument xdoc, class classname) {        
       var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(classname));
   ```
2. Can I make this method generic for all required types(`CarConfiguration`, `BikeConfiguration` etc.)? I mean for example dependency of return type on input class:

   ```
   static <classname> Deserialize(this XDocument xdoc, class classname) {
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key word in your question is `generic`, so yes you can do this by utilising [C# generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/). For example:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(this XDocument xdoc)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xdoc.ToString()))
    {
        T cfg = (T) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        return cfg;
    }
}
```

And now you call it like this:

```
CarConfiguration x = xmlDocument.Deserialize<CarConfiguration>();
```

Comment: Great! I knew it must be simple, but could not figure out what should I use:) Thanks.